# SQLite complex query

Tags: sql, sqlite

For page on my site I need to get list of all distinct usernames ordered descending by percentage of deleted tweets. And for column deleted1 1 means deleted tweet, 0 means not deleted (tweet exists), and 2 unknown. So I know this is complex query with GROUP BY... I could use help.

Here is table:

```
CREATE TABLE twitt_tb (
   link     TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
   username TEXT             NOT NULL,
   content  TEXT             NOT NULL,
   datum    INTEGER          NOT NULL,
   avatar   TEXT             NOT NULL,
   nik      TEXT             NOT NULL,
   deleted1 INTEGER  CHECK (deleted1 IN (0, 1, 2)) NOT NULL
);
```

Edit: Additional clarification: I need list of usernames ordered by percentage, and percentage for each user. Percentage calculated as users-deleted-tweets/total-tweets-of-that-user, and not as user-deleted-tweets/total-tweets-of-all-users.

Comment: Do you have any semblance of the total number of tweets?  You have `deleted1`, but that doesn't imply that you know the total number of tweets they've made to compare it with the number of tweets deleted.

Comment: No, this is all I have, I wanted to make db minimalistic. Total number of tweets for an username is `select username, count(*) where username='username' and deleted=0 or deleted=1 or deleted=2`

Comment: Or, more succintly: `select username, count(*) where username='username'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives the proportion of deleted tweets for a user -- of all tweets for the user that are known.

```
select username,
       (sum(case when delete1 = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) /
        sum(case when delete1 in (0, 1) then 1.0 else 0.0 end)
       ) as pdeleted
from twitt_tb t
group by username
order by pdeleted desc;
```

If you want to include all tweets for the user, you can formulate this as:

```
       (sum(case when delete1 = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) /
        count(*)
       ) as pdeleted
```

Or even more simply as:

```
avg(case when delete1 = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as pdeleted
```

This includes the proportion in the output.  If you wanted only the user name without the proportion, then put the formula in the `order by` clause instead of the `select` clause.

And finally, if you want this represented as a percent with a percentage sign, then you need to convert the number to a string and append a `'%'`.

Comment: Note that when converting it to a string and appending the '%', you want to be careful that you do that on a field that is NOT used by the 'order by', or else you could get surprising results from the ordering. Something like `select username, cast(round(pcnt,2)*100 as char)||'%' from (select username, avg(case when deleted1 = 1 then 1.0 else 0.0 end) as pcnt from twitt_tb group by username) order by pcnt desc` would be one method.

Comment: "The following gives the proportion of deleted tweets -- of all tweets that are known." I need usernames (and percentage for each user, you are right, I'll emphasize that by editing original post) ordered by percentage, but percentage calculated as users-deleted-tweets/total-tweets-of-thats-user. Not as user-deleted-tweets/total-tweets-of-all-users. Didn't quite understand what case is your solution of these two?

Comment: @SS . . . The calculation does what you want.